# EmberJS not displaying results from DS.RestAdapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm new to EmberJS and can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my code. I've read and compared different example projects hoping to find the "missing link" so I'd appreciate a second set of eyes on this:

I am using:

- handlebars.js 1.0.0-rc.3
- ember-latest.js (on AWS)
- ember-data-latest.js (on AWS)

Bleeding edge because I keep getting errors with whatever is on the website.

**index.html**:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
{{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="items">
  <h2>Total entries: {{length}}</h2>
  {{#if length}}
  <ul>
    {{#each item in controller}}
    <li>{{item.title}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
  {{/if}}
</script>
```

**app.js**:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

// Model
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    bulkCommit: false,
    url:        '/api'
  })
});

App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  id:    DS.attr('number'),
  title: DS.attr('string')
});

// Router
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('items', function () {
    this.resource('item', { path: ':item_id' });
  });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo('items');
  }
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function() {
    this.controllerFor('item').set('model', App.Item.find());
  }
});

App.ItemsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return App.Item.find();
  }
});

// Controller
App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['title']
});

App.ItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isEditing: false,

  editItem: function () {
    this.set('isEditing', true);
  }
});
```

On load, an XHR request is made to /api/items which returns as follows:

```
{"items":
  [
    {
      "id":"518c7ceeef56038b77000000",
      "title":"Test 1"
    },
    {
      "id":"518c7ceeef56038b77000001",
      "title":"Test 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

So data is being retrieved but somehow, it's just not appearing to the user!

Would appreciate some pointers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine your model is wrong, the `id` field in ember-data dosn't need to be specified explicitly if the name is `id`. A comment in the [source code](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/serializer.js#L132) reads:

> Get the primary key name for the record by calling
>        the serializer's `primaryKey` with the record's type.
>        Unless you override the `primaryKey` method, this
>        will be `'id'`.

Try to change your model to this simplified version:

```
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Hope it helps